# Returning a String array from Jquery ajax method using Spring MVC

Tags: arrays, string, jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to dynamically generate a list/dropdown using JQuery's .ajax method. Following is the code I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('in doc');
        $.ajax({
            url: "dyn/list",
            type: "GET",
            data: "list="+'',
            dataType: "json",
            error: function() {alert('eerrrr');},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
                alert(data);
                    $('#seltag').append(
                        $('<option></option>').html(data)
                    );
            },
            complete: function() {}
        });
        });</script>
```

And my corresponding controller method looks like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dyn/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getList(@RequestParam String list)
{
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    newList.add(opt0);
    newList.add(opt1);
    newList.add(opt2);
    return(new JSONArray(newList).toString());
    //return opt0;
}
```

Where opt0,1 and 2 are static string variables. Each time an error is returned. I have also tried .getJSON but to no avail. Help me out fellas!!

Comment: "Each time an error is returned." Help **us** out and tell us what that error is, that's going to make it considerably easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to convert to JSON yourself. Spring 3 with `<mvc:annotation-driven` enabled and jackson in the classpath does it for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dyn/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> getList(@RequestParam String list) {
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    newList.add(opt0);
    newList.add(opt1);
    newList.add(opt2);
    return newList;
}
```

For more info check out [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)

Comment: Thanks.. it worked fine. I am actually new to web development. So excuse me for incomplete info

Answer (score 2):

adding to oris answer, you need not do a getJSON too. Inside your success callback iterate throw the list a get the messages.

```
success: function(data) {
for(var count=0; count<data.length; count++){
 yourMessage = data[count];
}
//your code
}
```